# Stop adjusting size of ListView when keyboard is Active.[with images]. Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

[View without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx7BA.jpg)

[View with keyboard. The keyboard is on the background of the search view. It irritates user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZaE.jpg)

I don't want to come up listview every time I open the keyboard.
As you see from the second image, listview under search view is annoying for the user.
When keyboard is not active, all is ok.

I tried    `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
`adjustPan` and `adjustNothing`
Nothing works.

Comment: share your `xml` code here

Comment: @JamilHasnineTamim I just used relative layout instead of constraint.

Comment: So it's how to overlap over edit field! So I want to see your xml code

Comment: @JamilHasnineTamim Thanks! I don't need help anymore.

Comment: why? It's solved or what?

Comment: @JamilHasnineTamim It's solved!

Comment: Okay! great. Then delete or share your answer here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `ConstraintLayout`.
I switched my view to `RelativeLayout`!
Then, I put each element regarding.

Now, no overlap not as in Constraint Layout.

*Explanation:*
`ConstraintLayout` sets Elements by padding.
`RelativeLayout` sets Elements relatively to each other.

Comment: So, it was layout issue right! ;) So this point should be mine! Btw great job, though it's also possible in `ConstraintLayout`.